# Backward compatibility issues when migrating to use Jackson with Jersey

Tags: json, serialization, jersey, jackson, backwards-compatibility

I am using Jersey 1.16 for a restful service I provide to my client app.

I am trying to move from the default Jersey JSON serializer to use jackson based on this excellent blog entry:

http://crazytechbuddy.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/making-jersey-to-use-jackson-instead-of.html?showComment=1360271858862#c6459334450173933715

It worked great and seems to do just what I want. 
however it now creates backwards compatibility issues for my restful service.

for example: timestamp fields I had that used to be serialize as `"timestamp":"2012-12-25T14:22:24+02:00"` are now serialized as `"timestamp":1356438144000`.

Is there a way to select to activate the new jackson based serialization mode only on specific requests (possibly use a version parameter I have to decide what type of serialization to use) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson has lots of serialization options.  In your case you need to set:

```
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

if you are using Jackson 1.x or

```
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

if you are using Jackson 2.x.

To allow Jersey to access your custom `ObjectMapper` you need to create a provider:

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>
{
  private final transient ObjectMapper mapper;

  @Inject
  public ObjectMapperProvider()
  {
    this.mapper = MyMapper.getMapper();
  }

  @Override
  public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> type)
  {
    return this.mapper;
  }
}
```

Where `MyMapper.getMapper()` returns your custom `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: This looks appropriate when I use the mapper explicitly - right?
but what if its just used by Jersey ?

Comment: Added info on how to access your customer ObjectMapper.

Comment: Thanks.
I guess this should be in a package that is referenced by the com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages init-parameter for jersey.
I have not tested this as I already set up a solution for my current needs that uses @JSONSerialize. but it looks like a right and complete answer.